# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() from Mailchimp

Tags: wordpress, mailchimp

I want to know why I am getting an error `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

From this line of code and what data does it pass to the foreach loop

```
 //Mailchimp List
    $mail_chimp_list[]='';
    if(isset($cs_theme_options['cs_mailchimp_key'])){
        $mailchimp_option = $cs_theme_options['cs_mailchimp_key'];
        if($mailchimp_option <> ''){
            $mc_list = cs_mailchimp_list($mailchimp_option);
            if($mc_list <> ''){
                foreach($mc_list['data'] as $list){
                    $mail_chimp_list[$list['id']]=$list['name'];
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: that happens, cause foreach expects an array, and other object type is being passed, probably null (or false).

Answer (score 0):

I have also had this issue.  This issue is caused due to the mailchimp's update to the API. So here's is the solution. As you're getting this error in theme-options.php file which is placed in **directory-theme/include/theme-options/**. Now find the following line (line 175 in my case , it may be different in your case and will be shown to you as php error)

```
if($mc_list <> ''){
```

and replace it with

```
if(is_array($mc_list) && isset($mc_list['data'])){
```

I give you 1000% assurance of resolving the issue. :P